# Bash script reading text file - No such file Error

Tags: bash

I'm writing a script to read a simple text file.

But I get only a *"No such file"* message.

The file exist and has proper access rigths

the code I'm using is:

```
Ficheiro="mensagem"
while read linha; do
    echo $linha
done < Ficheiro
```

Comment: you may get the same error message even after including the $ sign, if your file isnt in the same directory. You might try specifying the absolute path.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a $

```
done < $Ficheiro
```